# How can I retrieve all the values from a particular column in amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

For example, if my `Question` table has columns `question_id`, `options`,`timestamp`, I must retrieve all the values of only 'question_id'.

Is it possible?

Comment: Generally, yes. To answer your question please provide a table scheme and the API you wish to get help with (There are at least 3 ways to get data from DynamoDB in Java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a `Scan` operation to read all the items regardless of any key value.

Second, you can use a `projection expression` to specify particular columns of the returned values from server side (to save network bandwidth). See [documentation page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.AccessingItemAttributes.html).

Comment: Hi, Below is my scan code written in Java that gives results of all the columns from the table. Could you help me, how may I add prejection expression to get only email_id column in the result?  ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName(TABLE_NAME).withScanFilter(keyConditions);

 AmazonDynamoDB client = dynamoDBService.getClient();
 ScanResult result = client.scan(scanRequest);