# How to fetch all the values of one column using column name in dynamoDB table in java?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb

I have a dynamoDB table in my aws account. I can create client like this.

```
AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB =
            AmazonDynamoDBClient.builder().withRegion("eu-west-1").withCredentials(creds).build();
    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(amazonDynamoDB);
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("table name");
```

Suppose there is column name "content". I want to get a list or set of all values in "content" column.

Comment: I don't think the AWS Java SDK supports PartiQL so you may have to scan the entire table and accumulate the column values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I retrieve all the values from a particular column in amazon DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804058/how-can-i-retrieve-all-the-values-from-a-particular-column-in-amazon-dynamodb)